# Show which iPads have been synced

Tags: itunes

I am with a school and we have several iPads that have been synced to our iTunes account.  I do not have these iPads in my office.  Can I tell by looking in my itunes account which iPads have been synced to my iTunes account?

Answer (score 3):

Look in preferences in iTunes and list all the devices that have a backup stored on the computer. If you didn't get a backup, then it becomes much less likely to catch any information from the system logs.

Grab yourself a copy of the iPhone configuration utility from the [enterprise support site](http://www.apple.com/support/iphone/enterprise/) and it will log each serial number and details every time it's running and you connect a device.

The [Apple Configurator](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-configurator/id434433123?mt=12) does similar but is intended more for management than just remembering all the devices. It also only runs on Macs running 10.7.2 or later.